# package_info_plus 4.0.1 issue with version number

Tags: flutter, plugins, version, package-info

I try to get the version of my app and the value is empty from PackageInfo. Please help!

```
PackageInfo packageInfo =
   await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
print('package info: $packageInfo');
```

And I try to print PackageInfo in terminal:

```
PackageInfo(appName: MyApp, buildNumber: 3, version: )
```

As you see is the version from response empty...
I have also tried:

```
Future getVersion() async {
    PackageInfo.fromPlatform().then((PackageInfo packageInfo) {
      setState(() {
        appName = packageInfo.appName;
        version = packageInfo.version;
        print('version: $version');
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:package_info_plus/package_info_plus.dart';

...

// Be sure to add this line if `PackageInfo.fromPlatform()` is called before runApp()
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

...

PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();

String appName = packageInfo.appName;
String packageName = packageInfo.packageName;
String version = packageInfo.version;
String buildNumber = packageInfo.buildNumber;
```